# HATEOAS paths are invalid when using an API Gateway in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, spring-hateoas

I have two spring boot applications where one of them is acting as an API Gateway (as discussed here [Spring Example](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv)). The other which is wired into the first one is exposing a profile service using spring-data-rest (spring-data-neo4j-rest).

The first application is starting on port 8080 and is using zuul to route requests to the second as follows:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    profiles:
      path: /profiles/**
      url: http://localhost:8083/profiles/
```

This all works fine and requests to http://localhost:8080/profiles are being served from the second app. The problem though is that the HATEOAS links in the response are incorrect. The response from calling that second service are correct:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8083/profiles{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "search": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8083/profiles/search"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "profiles": [
            {
                "name": "Andrew Rutter",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8083/profiles/0"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Andrew Rutter",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8083/profiles/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 2,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

But when this comes back to my API Gateway, the links are being rewritten to

```
{
  "name": "Andrew Rutter",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profiles/profiles/0"
    }
  }
}
```

Which is the gateway path alias plus the actual service base Uri. Am I missing a zuul option to disable that behavior and just leave the hateoas uri in place with a host adjustment. Or is there a way for my service behind the gateway to be wired to / rather then the default resource endpoint of /profiles (in this case) which would avoid the undesirable path being added in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Zuul or Spring-Cloud adds the "X-Forwarded-Host" header to all the forwarded requests, which Spring-hateoas respects and modifies the links appropriately. To quote from Spring-Cloud docs:

> The X-Forwarded-Host header added to the forwarded requests by
>   default. To turn it off set zuul.addProxyHeaders = false. The prefix
>   path is stripped by default, and the request to the backend picks up a
>   header "X-Forwarded-Prefix" ("/myusers" in the examples above).

You can try the recommended fix, which is to set the `zuul.addProxyHeaders=false`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The result of setting that to false is that the links returned are the direct links to the backend service which is undesirable. I noticed that the spring-hateoas version being brought in was 0.16.0 so have tried changing that dependency up to current but no joy. I did change the api path to /xyz in the gateway to make things more clear. When I request a specific profile as /xzy/0, this is sent internally to /profiles/0 but the hateoas link in the response ends up as /xyz/profiles/0/profiles/0

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. Change your config as follows:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    profiles:
      path: /profiles/**
      url: http://localhost:8083
      stripPrefix: false
```

This routes all  requests going to the gateway matching "/profiles/**" to your back end server "http://localhost:8083" and leaves the prefix (in your case "/profiles" since that's what matched the route).

Answer (score 0):

Zuul forwards to the /profiles contextPath.

Try setting this as configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    profiles:
      path: /profiles/**
      url: http://localhost:8083/
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that already and the context path from the original request is not passed across to the service. In the above example, I get a 404 that there is nothing available on / since Spring Data Rest exposes endpoints based on the model which is /profiles/* for this example but the gateway does not pass that across automagically

Comment: Have you tried 
    zuul:
      routes:
        profiles:
          path: /**
          url: http://localhost:8083/profiles/
?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling some time with the same problem, finally I've tried `zuul.addProxyHeaders = true` and it works!
Links are not broken anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the demo app I used for SpringOne in my talk about Spring Data REST, I have the following configuration to both handle URI rewrites as well as adjust prefix headers set properly.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    api:
      path: /api/**
      serviceId: spring-a-gram-backend
      stripPrefix: false
    files:
      path: /files/**
      serviceId: spring-a-gram-mongodb-fileservice
      stripPrefix: false
```

See it in full at https://github.com/gregturn/spring-a-gram/blob/master/spring-a-gram-frontend/src/main/resources/application.yml#L23-L32