# What headers should be used when combining URI-rewrites and HATEAOS?

Tags: reverse-proxy, hateoas

Let's say I have a Foo service that accepts requests like:

```
http://foo-service/bar/baz
```

...and returns HATEOAS-style responses:

```
{
  "self": "http://foo-service/bar/baz"
}
```

*(Yes it should be `links`, `href`, etc - I'm simplifying for this question).*

Now suppose I want to put that behind a reverse-proxy that also rewrites URI paths:

```
http://router/foo/bar/baz
```

*(Here, I'm detecting the path starts with `/foo/...`, and so the reverse-proxy knows what service to route to. I would expect the `self` link to be `"http://router/foo/bar/baz"`, even though the reverse-proxy actually made a request to `http://foo-service/bar/baz`).*

I know about the `Host:` and `X-Forwarded-Host:` headers for specifying what the original request host was.

What is the correct header (or more generally, what is the correct way) for specifying the original path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a possible answer: it seems to be **X-Forwarded-Prefix**.

eg: [HATEOAS paths are invalid when using an API Gateway in a Spring Boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584242/hateoas-paths-are-invalid-when-using-an-api-gateway-in-a-spring-boot-app)